# Modal iframe img jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, modal-dialog, image

I have a list of names which upon being clicked on opens a fancybox modal and displays an iframe with the HTML file as the src. The HTML file contains an image of the person and a short bio.

I want the image to be floated right and a padding of 10px. Problems is, I haven't been able to access it with css or jQuery either because the way fancy box works or the way the HTML files were exported (they were created by someone else using inDesign, so there is all this weird stuff --

```
    !--[if gte mso 10]>
    
     /* Style Definitions */
     table.MsoNormalTable
        {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
        mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
    ....
```

... and so on

I have gone in manually and changed most of the files style for the images --

```
 img { float:right; padding:right;}
```

This worked for most of the files, but a few (specifically some guy name Don Horton) even if I go into the img tag and style it NOTHING happens --

```
 `img src="/Horton_Don.html" style="float:right; padding:10px;"`
```

Doesn't work.

I've also attempted several jQuery functions here's an example:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        $('img').css("float", "right").css("padding", "10px");
    });
```

but I feel this doesn't work because the fancybox, or maybe it's the iframe.

So my question is:

A) is there a simple way to change all the images in every HTML file through jQuery (cause that would save me alot of time rather than going in every file manually)

B) is there something that has to do with the inDesign crap that is keeping me from changing the img stuff, if so can someone give me an idea as to what to look for/a link explaining how inDesign exports html.

I'm trying to be clear cut here, if it's confusing I can upload some bigger code segments for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a CSS file on your server that holds reference to these styles.

**The CSS File**

*we refer to this file as myStyles.css* for the purpose of this example.

```
img{
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Looks like fancybox has an onComplete api callback function.

```
$('ele').fancybox({
    'onComplete' : function(){

        var cssItem = document.createElement("link") 
        cssLink.href = "myStyles.css"; 
        cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
        cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
        frames['myIframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
    }
});
```

Where myIframe is the name of the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This is half a guess and half a hack, but for A, you could use $.get() on the page and assign that to a variable. Then, you can use that variable as a context for any edits.

```
var page = $.get('page.html');
$('img', page).css('float', 'right').css('padding', '10px');
```

All jQuery selections take an optional "context" parameter that specifies what HTML the selector should act on. Your iframe would of course have to point to the page variable for the changes to be visible.

This is kind of a  shot in the dark, hope it helps.